# How do I replace date format using TextPad?

Tags: regex, date, textpad

How do I do a replace using TextPad for all date occurrences such as

01-Apr-2014
02-Apr-2014
03-Apr-2014

to

2014-Apr-01
2014-Apr-02
2014-Apr-03

I tried a bunch of regular expressions for the date, but can't even get it working once. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(\d+)-(\w+)-(\d+)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/mS3qW2/1)**

And then change the order of capturing group index:

[image]

Comment: I tried it in TextPad, but i keep getting "Cannot find literal expression: (\d+)-(\w+)-(\d+)"

Comment: @Candice as you can see in my answer it works fine. I think that TextPad doesn't support this or it could have a bug. You can try using Notepad++ or even paste the text in regex101.com. Btw, if my answer answered to your question you may consider marking it as resolved.

Comment: i have text before and after the dates, so do i need a wildcard character in the regex and in the substitution?

Answer (score 0):

The expressions below work in Textpad. Federico was using POSIX syntax which you have to specifically tell Textpad to use in Configure>Properties>Editor. Also, you got a "literal expression" not found, meaning you didn't check the regular expression checkbox in the search window.

Find What: ([0-9]+)-([a-z]+)-([0-9]+)
Replace With: \3-\2-\1

[image: Search Box Image]